# jQuery slideToggle problem when using height %

Tags: jquery, height, slidetoggle, css

I can't figure out why slideToggle causes the 2 panels to grow outside of the parent div when height uses a % value:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle(5000);
    $(".panel2").slideToggle(5000);
  });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
div.parent
{
height:300px;
width:600px;
background:red;
}
div.panel,p.flip,div.panel2
{
width:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.panel
{
height:100%;
display:none;
}
div.panel2
{
height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="panel">
        <p>Panel 1: Because time is valuable</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel2">
        <p>Panel 2: Because time is valuable</p>
    </div>
    <p class="flip">Show Panel</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I change the height to a fixed px value, the behavior performs as expected. Essentially I want the 2 panels to swipe between each other.

Comment: you may want to accept some answers to your questions, if you continue to want answers. Just common courtesy.

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding is knowing that slideToggle is changing the CSS height attribute on the element.  Additionally, you have a height specified on your panels as 100% of the parent.  However, you also have a P tag in there which really has no space allocated to it in the parent.

This situation of having overlapping elements due to invalid height definitions is screwing up jQuery's calculations.

This fix is shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/DwTRQ/

Set the paragraph to have an absolute position, or just remove it from the parent panel.

Oh, and I should also mention that because of how the CSS box model works, having an element set to 100% of height or width with a padding won't work well for you.  It'll scale beyond the parents boundaries.

Comment: Understood, the p tag was just for identifying each div and getting an idea of how the content would be effected by the toggle. In my project at home I am planning to have a majority of the content effected by this slide. The next step is to figure out how to get it to slide left and right without distorting any of the content. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Steve, if you found my answer to be accurate, please click the checkmark next to it on the left side so it's green.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of height value in %. 100% of 300 is 300. So when panel1 grows to 100% i.e 300px then panel2 has to come out of the parent to increase the height. You should give the height in px to make it work as expected.

Comment: Well my interest in using % values is that in my project at home I have a parent div set to a specific px value and every child of that div has a %, and every child of those children also has %. So on and so forth. I thought that was a good idea because I would only have to change 2 px values if I wanted to scale the site accordingly. I was hoping to keep that idea going when I got this toggle effect running, but it sounds like I will have to go back to using px values or write some sort of work around using animate()